# How can I get form content in JSON format from request object using PATCH HTTP method?

Tags: php, json, forms, symfony, http

I'm trying to retrieve form data in a JSON from a request object in symfony. I'm familiar with using POST and GET methods, and retrieving data with `$request->request->get('something')`, but this doesn't work with PATCH. (returns null, which means that nothing exists under 'something').

When dumping the variable's content with 
`var_dump($request->getcontent());`
my JSON shows up after some XML tags, but I can't extract it.

Is there any way I can get it easily, like when using the POST method?

```
$form =$this->createForm(ProjectUpdateType::class, $project);
$data = json_decode($request->request->get('project'),true);
$form->submit($data, true);
```

`$data` becomes null using this method, because
`$request->request->get('project')` is `null`.
But as I mentioned, the JSON is there somewhere, but I don't know how to extract it. 
Thank you in advance!

```
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'> 
    <small>/vagrant/src/Controller/ProjectController.php:129:</small>
    <small>string</small> 
        <font color='#cc0000'>'-----------------------------100229165918779178541068782244&#13;&#10;Content-Disposition: form-data; name=&quot;project&quot;&#13;&#10;&#13;&#10;{&quot;title&quot;:&quot;newTitle&quot;,&quot;description&quot;:&quot;NewDescription&quot;,&quot;priority&quot;:false}&#13;&#10;-----------------------------100229165918779178541068782244--&#13;&#10;'</font> 
        <i>(length=244)</i> 
</pre>
```

Comment: Can you show us (in your question) the result of the `var_dump($request->getcontent());`

Comment: I guess you missed the bit about **(in your question)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON is there in the body, and `$request->getContent()` is the only proper way to get to it. The problem here is not that you can't get the JSON - it's that the response contains more than just the JSON object, or in other words, an invalid JSON. If, however, the API that you're using is actually supposed to return a JSON inside an XML document, then you have to parse this XML first, using [SimpleXML](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) for example.